# Bounded bessel functions in an s-set projection proof

Tags: improper-integrals, fractals, geometric-measure-theory, bessel-functions

The following is an extract from Falconer's Geometry of Fractal Sets about the proof of:

[image]

"...Using the definition of a Bessel function $J_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 \cos(u \cos \theta) d\theta$...

[image]

I really cannot understand how the integral of $J_0$ is bounded? This corresponds to the inequality in the section above. I have tried to look at properties of Bessel functions without joy. Furthermore I think this is complicated as it is a $J$ type bessel function. (I may be wrong).

I have tried to find justification in Watson's A treatise on the theory of bessel functions but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplace transform of $J_0(x)$ is well-known to be $1/\sqrt{1+s^2}$, i.e.
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} J_0(x)e^{-sx}\,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}.
$$
If you let $s\to 0^+$ (justify that this is valid), you find that
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} J_0(x)\,dx = 1.
$$
Hence,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} J_0(x)\,dx = 2,
$$
since $J_0$ is even.

Comment: Yes, using the formula of the Fourier transform given in that pdf file also works. Your integral is the Fourier transform evaluated at zero.

Comment: One definition of $J_0$ is $J_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(x\sin t)\,dt$. It follows directly by the evenness of the cosine function that $J_0$ is even. Btw, the book by Watson is a good book on Bessel functions.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't $J_0(u)$ given by a cosine integral? For real $u$, it seems clear that $|J_0(u)|\leq 1$. Do you mean the integral of $J_0(u)$?

Comment: Yes integral of $J_0$. Will edit question soon to make this clearer